# How to start the "Icecrown-Citadel" raid with level 80?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

How do i start the "Icecrown-Citadel" raid with level 80? I read in some forums that it is possible to do the raid with level 80 despite the "Raid-finder" is unlocked with level 85. I'm relatively new to the game and would appreciate a good explanation. So... 
 Do i have to find other players and build an own group? 
or
Is there another possibility?

Comment: Back in my day, we didn't have any of this newfangled "finder" technology. You just had to zone-chat for 30 minutes trying to get a team together to run through even a simple dungeon! Whippersnappers.

Comment: @nukeforum You mean Trade chat in cities as that's where everyone spammed for raid invites back in the day.

Comment: @Powerlord Well, yeah, for raids. But if you wanted to do dm back in the day, you'd sit in Westfall and zone chat forever trying to get a group together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to have to do it the old fashioned way and get a group of people together manually. Then just fly out to Ice Crown Citadel and start summoning in people who want to come.

Keep in mind, you probably won't find a lot of people who are exactly 80 to run your through. Some 100s will come along and just blow through the raid.